# Error in tune.svm() when using categorical features in R, package e1071

Tags: r, svm

I'm creating an SVM for two-class classification with R package e1071, using functions svm() and tune.svm() and a set of around 10 numerical features. svm() works fine and tune.svm() too, producing even better results with optimized C and gamma parameters.

However, when I add a categorical variable to my set of features, svm() still works fine, but tune.svm() produces the following error:

```
Error in if (any(co)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I cannot make sense of this error message. The categorical variable has 5 levels, and everyone of them is represented in the data. In my unexperience, it seems like tune.svm() cannot handle creating and tuning an SVM when there are categorical features involved, but I'm sure there has to be a straightforward solution to this, something I'm missing.

Despite looking through the (often rather concise) e1071 manuals to be found online, and finding several forum threads on related topics (errors with tune.svm() etc.), I haven't been able to find an answer to this specific situation. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is it possible for you to link the data you are using?

Comment: Also, did you convert the categorical column to factors before using it in the model? Check the class for that column. What does it say?